# How to beep using PC speaker?

Tags: c#, hardware, beep

I want to make a beep sound using PC speaker in C#. When using the following code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "Beep", SetLastError = true,
ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool Beep(uint frequency, uint duration);

static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Beep(1000, 500);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

instead of beeping through the PC speaker, it simply outputs a sound of a given frequency and duration to the default sound device (as a headset for example). The same thing happens when using `Console.Beep()`.

Why?

Notes:

- The PC speaker is on. When I start the PC, it beeps.
- The OS is Windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any 32 bit Windows machines lying around? Try `Console.Beep();` on one of those, the PC speaker will beep.

On 64 bit Windows (XP, Vista, 7 or 8) the driver to do this isn't present so it will come out of the speaker plugged into the machine instead.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong but I would hazard a guess that the beep you hear whenever your PC turns on is from your BIOS, before you actually hit Windows 8.

Comment: +1 said that as well, as for windows 8 32bit the pc beep uses the sound card as well. I own a 32 bit machine so i speak from experience.

Answer (score 6):

From Windows 7 onwards, you can no longer easily make sound via the internal speaker.

> For Windows 7, we resolved the issue completely – we moved all the functionality that used to be contained in Beep.Sys into the user mode system sounds agent – now when you call the Beep() API instead of manipulating the 8254 chip the call is re-routed into a user mode agent which actually plays the sounds.

[…]

> There were also some unexpected consequences.  The biggest was that people started noticing when applications called Beep().  They had placed their PCs far enough away (or there was enough ambient noise) that they had never noticed when their PC was beeping at them until the sounds started coming out their speakers.

See here for details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7

Comment: Awesome blog article, but maybe thats just the electrical engineer in me ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SystemSounds.Beep` for example: `SystemSounds.Beep.Play();`

See also: [SystemSounds.Beep Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.beep.aspx)

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the OP's exact question, this gave me an answer for a simple request: a quick little sound I can use via .NET, purely programmatically. Thanks, Ekk!