# Programmatically play sounds from the internal computer speakers c#

Tags: c#, audio

I'm trying to make it so my program can play beeps from the internal speaker on computer(ignoring sound cards/speakers attached to the computer)

Below is some example code that works fine on an old XP machine that I have using the internal speakers, so I can mute sounds on the computer but still hear the beeps, but when using it on my Windows 8 computer it will use the default playback device and if I disable all the playback devices it does nothing.

```
Console.Beep(698, 125);
Console.Beep(698, 125);
Thread.Sleep(625);
Console.Beep(784, 125);
Console.Beep(740, 125);
Console.Beep(698, 125);
```

Is there any limitations to using this method that won't work with certain operating systems or any way to make it specifically target the computers on board speakers?

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794846/how-to-beep-using-pc-speaker the 64-bit version of Windows doesn't support it. (The official docs only mention XP and Vista though)

Comment: http://bit.ly/TATQqU suggests that you can't do that as of Windows 7.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx