# Play sound on laptop speaker, even if additional speakers are connected (but not listed in device list)

Tags: c#, windows, audio, hardware

I'd like to play a soundfile from the speakers integrated in the laptop, even if an additional speaker is connected via the headphone jack (but it's not listed in the sound device list).

I've had a look at [How can I make the computer beep in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321135/how-can-i-make-the-computer-beep-in-c) and [How to beep using PC speaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794846/how-to-beep-using-pc-speaker) and have understood that the [beep driver was removed in windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/%22beep%20driver%20was%20removed%20in%20windows%207%22).

However, I do not want to use this extremely simple integrated speaker controlled by the removed driver, but the normal one present in most modern laptops.

Unfortunately, when I connect my external speakers, they do not show up as an additional device. When I run this code (using NAudio), I always get just one result, and it's the same whether the external speakers are connected or not:

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
foreach (var endpoint in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active))
{
    Console.WriteLine(endpoint.FriendlyName);
}
```

Is it possible to play a sound on the normal laptop speaker, while an external speaker is connected?

Edit:
I don't think my question is a duplicate of [Play a sound in a specific device with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868966/play-a-sound-in-a-specific-device-with-c-sharp)
I don't see an additional device when I connect my external speakers, so I guess my laptop doesn't have multiple sound cards (how can I verify?).
The solution from the other question (`waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;`) doesn't work for me neither. When I choose `deviceNumber = 0;`, the sound comes from my external speaker if it's connected. If I set `deviceNumber = 1;` (while it's connected) I get a `MmException`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play a sound in a specific device with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868966/play-a-sound-in-a-specific-device-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't think so, I added an explanation to my question

Comment: I think that is due to that the output might be directly linked to your laptop speakers/sound card, meaning the sound is probably physically redirected if a cable/line exists.

Comment: Is it possible to test this?

Comment: In Vincent case, are you able to force addressing both outputs?

Comment: @Christopher : Don't know. It could also depend on your sound drivers. But my (standalone) speakers for my desktop PC have an output in them, which just redirects the sound if plugged in. And my laptop behaves just like your laptop and my desktop PC's speakers.

Comment: USB speakers/headsets shouldn't behave like this though, as they require additional drivers to work.

Answer (score 0):

I see I'm a bit late for the party but i was working on something similar and got to this solution.
Hope it helps someone in the future :)

```cs
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
IWavePlayer waveOut = new WasapiOut();
foreach (var endpoint in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active))
{
    if (endpoint.FriendlyName == "Name of the device you want")
    {
        waveOut = new WasapiOut(
            endpoint, AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, false, 0);

        AudioFileReader wave = new AudioFileReader("Audio Name");

        waveOut.Init(wave);
        waveOut.Play();
        break;
    }
}
```